# Is it possible to grouping two apps and showing them when using ALT+TAB in windows 10?

Tags: windows, alt-tab

i'm new on `Superuser` and sorry if i ask on a wrong place.

I have two apps (`vs code & emulator Nox`), and because i'm not maximise a `vscode`, i want to group an `emulator` with my `vscode`, so if i'm alt+tab `vscode` or `emulator`, i want to show up these two apps together not only one,
it is possible?

something like this:

[image]

Comment: "is it possible?" - If it's possible third-party software would be required.  I am not aware of any software that would do what you describe.

Comment: i don't mind if i need to installed 3rd-party software, but i'm not find it, so i think someone would suggest me if i asking

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

No, this is not possible with `ALT`+`TAB`. The behavior of `ALT`+`TAB` is to switch between graphical applications, which means that only one can have focus.

However, you can use `WIN`+`TAB` to use multiple desktops and this will get you what you're after ("application groups") and you can couple that along with `ALT`+`TAB` to switch between apps within each desktop.

Open `vscode` and `nox` as you normally would. Press `WIN`+`TAB` and click `+ New Desktop` to create a second Desktop. Use `WIN`+`TAB` to switch to the second desktop and open the "other" applications you use (browser, email, whatever) on the second desktop. When you want to switch to `vscode` and `nox` just press `WIN`+`TAB` again and select that desktop from the list. Press again to switch back.

Comment: upvoted for a trick, but i would avoid it since `WIN`+`TAB` is more slowly than `ALT`+`TAB`

Comment: of course it is, you're switching between application groups not just applications. you can disable desktop animation to reduce most of the lag. (`Settings`, `Ease of Access`, `Display`, `Show animations in Windows`)

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't natively support what you are after, but you can achieve it using free automation software, such as Autohotkey.

Install Autohotkey, create a script (just create a text file then change the file extension to .ahk), then paste this:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Start:

GroupAdd, WindowGroup, ahk_class YOURWINDOW1
GroupAdd, WindowGroup, ahk_class YOURWINDOW2
WinWaitActive, ahk_group WindowGroup
Winactivate, ahk_class YOURWINDOW1
Winactivate, ahk_class YOURWINDOW2
WinwaitNotActive, ahk_group WindowGroup

Goto Start
```

Ahk_class is just an identifier for windows on your desktop. Like a label. Where it says YOURWINDOW in the above code, replace it with the ahk_classes of the windows of the apps you want to group together so they both appear together when you switch to either one of them using Alt-Tab.

To find out the ahk_class of the window for your apps, you need to install a little app (or a portable version so no install) which tells you the name of windows on your desktop. For example, AU3-Spy, Window Detective, Winspy, or some other such app.

Run the window identifier software, click on the window you want to find the ahk_class for, and look at where it says the window's ahk_class.  Just put whatever is there in place of YOURWINDOW1, then do the same for the other window and replace where it says YOURWINDOW2.