# Is there any program or way to make Windows' Alt-Tab behave like Mac OS X's ⌘-Tab?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to switch between programs, not individual windows from every program. I believe this is how Windows used to work back in Windows XP.

When you switch between programs in macOS, you switch between applications showing their icon. When you select the program, it opens every window for that program.

[image: Switch app on macOS.]

When you use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in windows, a thumbnail of each window shows.

[image: Alt Tab in Windows]

Is there a program or shortcut in Windows to make <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> function like macOS?

This is the opposite question as this one: [Is there any program or way to make Mac OS X's ⌘-Tab behave like Windows' Alt-Tab? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/193922/is-there-any-program-or-way-to-make-mac-os-xs-tab-behave-like-windows-alt-ta)

The closest program I have found was from NeoSmart Technologies, Link: [Easy Window Switcher](https://neosmart.net/blog/easy-window-switcher/)

But I wasn't able to get it to work on Windows 11.

Comment: I don't have a Mac so can not compare, but does this help: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/classic-icons-on-alt-tab-windows-10/

Comment: NVM, it's not exactly what you're asking, it still does icon for each individual instance. I applied it myself anyway because I think it's an improvement over thumbnails.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen this is much closer to what I am looking for. This would be perfect if it counted Explorer as 1 icon. I would submit this as an answer. I would still like to see if there is a better solution but so far this is closest to what I am looking for. It's a little odd that some icons do not show :/ They use a default icon for Spotify and settings on my end.

Comment: Well, first, you can set groups of apps and switch between them with AHK https://superuser.com/questions/1502213/is-it-possible-to-grouping-two-apps-and-showing-them-when-using-alttab-in-windo

Comment: Secondly, how about WIN+TAB? you'll need to arrange each app on its own desktop, but this might help?

Comment: @Netan this might be the best solution for my workflow. You should submit this as an answer. I will use virtual desktop, and then AutoHotKey from here [How can I change the keys to change desktop in windows 10 with autohotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685314/how-can-i-change-the-keys-to-change-desktop-in-windows-10-with-autohotkey) to switch between desktops. I can then pin programs using the answer from here [Assigning a virtual desktop to a monitor in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/965385/assigning-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-windows-10) for my second monitor

Comment: Yet **another** reason to stay faraway from Windows 11 (not that I needed one) and perhaps an incentive to go back to Win7 .... Thanks! This is valuable info.,

Comment: @AndrewH Glad it helps. Posted. I hope you'll find a better solution soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments:

First, you can set groups of apps and switch between them with AHK [like here](https://superuser.com/questions/1502213/is-it-possible-to-grouping-two-apps-and-showing-them-when-using-alttab-in-windo)

Also, how about <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>? you'll need to arrange each app on its own desktop, but it might be another resolution?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you want but:

**Classic icons on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>**

Open the registry editor with admin rights and navigate to the following key.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

Right-click the Explorer key and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name the new value AltTabSettings

Double-click it and set its value to 1 to get classic icons on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Restart Windows Explorer to execute the change. To restart Windows Explorer, open the Task Manager and go to the Processes tab. Look for, and select Windows Explorer. Click the Restart button at the bottom right and when you next tap the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcut, you will see the following app switcher.

[image]

Source: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/classic-icons-on-alt-tab-windows-10/

Comment: For some reason, several applications do not use their icon, see the first icon in your image. Applications (for me at least) like Spotify, InDesign, and settings use the same icon. You also cannot use your mouse to select an icon. Still I like this more. I can always use Windows+Tab if I want to select by thumbnail preview.

Comment: Yes, I see the same here. Quite annoying.

Comment: Seem to be MS Store apps, for one.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can switch between open windows and programs by pressing the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Knowing the program number in Taskbar, you can use shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (where n is the program number in Taskbar) to switch between the windows of a specific program.

For example, if File Explorer is the third icon in Taskbar, Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> repeatedly will switch between all open File Explorer windows.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I already know about Alt+Tab, I wrote the shortcut wrong in my question, I have now fixed it. My question is about group same programs so I can easily switch between several programs and not individual windows.

Comment: @AndrewH, I completed my answer with new details.

Comment: Pretty close to what I am looking for but I have some issues. It's not as convenient as macOS where you can cycle between programs and only have to use 1 shortcut. This method does not show all windows of that program when you select it. So if I have 4 Window Explorer open, then I have to do the shortcut 4 times to show them all.

Comment: That's right, but as far as I know, there is no other built-in feature in Windows for this. It's one of many differences between Windows and macOS. You need a dedicated software for that in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Auto Hot Key, I made a small program implementing Mac switcher behavior on Windows. It's standalone `.exe` to launch.

I just released the first version, so there are limitations, but if you'd like to give a try, please check:

- https://github.com/hdlx/MacAppSwitcher

Answer (score -3):

I have never needed nor tried to implement this in Winblows. However, you can try autohotkey and the following autohotkey script:

Autohotkey: https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey

Autohotkey script:

https://github.com/jendakol/autohotkey/blob/main/window-switch-multiple.ahk